# jqGrid - duplicate IDs when key kolumn is 0

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I have a issue with jqGrid and I can't come over it.
My server sends back to client list of 15 records. Each has an unique ID (from DB) and a number (server generated when rendering JSON).

Problem is that one of the records has ID=0. jqGrid does not put this ID as identifier of row in table, but instead takes next column (number) as row identifier which results in duplicate row ids and issues with selection. This happens only when key column is equal to 0.

What can be done to get rid of that issue?

Comment: why not do a +1 for all the unique IDs so nothing would be zero?

Comment: I'd like this ids to be consistent with those from DB since I invoke some ajax with id as param.

Comment: could you include the JSON data which you use and the grid definition (especially `jsonReader`, `colModel` etc)? Do you use editing of the data or need to display the data only?